# Can't pass a function to props

Tags: reactjs

I begin with `React` and it seems that `props` only accepts values and not functions?
I get an error while I try to do this:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                hey there! {this.props.x}
            </div>
        );
    },
    calcul: function(a, b){
        return a*b
    }
});

React.render(
    <Hello x={this.calcul(5, 6)}/>,
    document.getElementById('content')
)
```

I get this `Uncaught TypeError: this.calcul is not a function`

But when I use `x={this.calcul}` it fails silently.

Comment: `Hello.calcul(5,6)` also doesn't work?

Comment: Your `calcul` function resides inside the scope of `Hello` component but when using `React.render(...)` to try and render the `Hello` component, you are outside of the scope of `Hello` component, so `this` would refer to `window` object most probably and hence, `calcul` function is not to be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.calcul` doesn't exist because `this` is bound to the global context in this case. If you wanted to pass the result of `calcul` as a prop:

```
function calcul(a, b) {
  return a*b;
}

var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
          hey there! {this.props.x}
      </div>
    );
  },
  calcul: calcul
});

React.render(
  <Hello x={calcul(5, 6)} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

So here `30` would be passed as prop x and your component will have the `calcul` function.

Comment: That worked! and since this is a kind of a workaround, that means i am not doing something in a React-way :D thank you again

Comment: Edit: removing `calcul: calcul` will also work with `x={calcul(5, 6)}`, it will use the initial function, if there is `calcul = calcul` then it should be better to use `x={this.calcul(5, 6)}`

Answer (score 1):

I think the "React" way could be something like this

```
  var Calculator = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                hey there! {this.calcul(this.props.x, this.props.y)}
            </div>
        );
    },
    calcul: function(a, b){
        return a*b;
    }
});

React.render(
    <Calculator x={5} y={6}/>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

But there are a LOT of ways of doing this.